# Show/Hide Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem, I have this hide function that is not working for me.

What I'm doing is that a pop up with a referral will show within 5 seconds of starting a video and I want it to be hidden after about 5 seconds.
Someone can help me or advise me what to do.
Thank you very much
regards

```
 function showComingNext() {
    if (!showingComingNext) {
      showingComingNext = true;
      angular.element($document[0].getElementsByClassName('kaltura-player')[0]).prepend($compile('<fw-player-coming-next></fw-player-coming-next>')($scope));
    }
  }

  function hideComingNext() {

    if (showingComingNext) {
    if (!$document[0].getElementById('#player-coming-next')[0])
      showingComingNext = false;
      angular.element($document[0].getElementById('#player-coming-next')[0]).remove();
    }
  }
```

---

```
          kalturaPlayer.addJsListener('playerUpdatePlayhead', function(ms) {

            ms = Math.floor(ms);
            if (!duration) {
              duration = Math.floor(kalturaPlayer.evaluate('{mediaProxy.entry.msDuration}') / 1000);
            }
            if (ms > 5 ) {
              showComingNext();
            }
            else  {
              hideComingNext();
            }
```

Comment: read the post once and see if it is meaningful. where is the ng-show or ng-hide in this question?

Comment: You can use ng-hide and ng-show, pls post your entire code html and js file so that issue gets clearer

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?